# SVG icons do not show up when remotely connected

Tags: 8

I have installed Drupal 8 in my linux machine for testing. Everything seems fine initially when I'm accessing D8 from my local machine.

However when I tried to access it via another machine on the same network, the svg icons do not show up. After further investigation using firefox element inspect, I realized some of the request urls are from 192.168.1.18, which is my linux machine IP, while the rest are either from localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Am I missing any configuration here?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I realized some of the request urls are from 192.168.1.18, which is my linux machine IP, while the rest are either from localhost or 127.0.0.1.

I assume you mean "request URLs are **to** 192.168.1.18". This is normal Drupal behavior because some file asset URLs are cached in the HTML output.

Clear the site caches.

Notice you can set $settings['file_public_base_url'] in settings.php which will make the asset URLs consistent.

Comment: Thanks alot. This helps. I've set the file_public_base_url accordingly previously but didn't realize I'll have to clear the cache.

Am i able to use relative path instead of full path "http://192.168.1.18/..." in file_public_base_url? I have tried a few combination of relative paths but they don't seem to work?

Comment: In normal (non-CDN) situations you should not need to set $ file_public_base_url. The problem in your development site is that you are accessing it by IP address, not by a host name. If you set up virtual hosts on your workstation's web server and edit its host file, it will be possible to access this development site at whatever.example.com on your workstation or on the network, and this problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your code you dont reference the icon like http://127.0.0.1/sites/default/somepath/youricon.svg but you re using a relative path instead like sites/default/somepath/youricon.svg.

Comment: It is a clean d8 installation I have not put any modules / codes in yet in this case.

Thanks for the tips of using relative path by the way.